# UICollectionView Custom Cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to build my swift program on Swift 3.1.
I could build it. 
However it can not work properly from Swift 3.1.

I got the following error.

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier SingleItemCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier
```

However,i already regist SingleItemCell for uicollectionview.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      //エリア情報の表示に必要なxibをcollectionviewに登録
      var nib = UINib(nibName: "ItemCell", bundle:nil)
      areaView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"ItemCell")

      nib     = UINib(nibName: "SingleItemCell", bundle:nil)
      areaView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"SingleItemCell")

      nib     = UINib(nibName: "SftCollectionReusableView", bundle:nil)
      areaView.register(nib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "SftCollectionReusableView")
      areaView.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "EmptyView")

      areaView.dataSource = dataSourcedelegate
      areaView.delegate = dataSourcedelegate

      ....
  }


  /**
 セル一つ一つの定義

 - parameter collectionView: <#collectionView description#>
 - parameter indexPath:      <#indexPath description#>

 - returns: <#return value description#>
 */
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    return configureCell(collectionView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

/**
 各セルの表示

 - parameter collectionView: <#collectionView description#>
 - parameter indexPath:      <#indexPath description#>

 - returns: <#return value description#>
 */
 func configureCell(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0{

        return areaItemCell(collectionView, indexPath: indexPath)
    }else{
        let cell:SingleItemCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SingleItemCell", for: indexPath) as! SingleItemCell
        cell.itemLabel.text = "現在地から検索"
        cell.itemLabel.addImage("common_here_icon",font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20),marginx: -5,intLabelMode: ImageLabelMode.left.hashValue)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Itemcell is loaded.
However SingleItemCell is not loaded.
Why it was not loaded even if I register.

What is this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve by myself.
I attache my fix capture.

[image]

I changed the calling order of methods.
Then,my system work properly.
My probelm is that

```
viewModel.areas.asObservable().bindTo(areaView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSourcedelegate))
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

above method is called before getting registering custom cell.